# Colouring markers in a scatter plot when using a Pandas DataFrame with a timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm struggling to figure out how to make a scatter plot using Matplotlib when using a Pandas DataFrame which contains a timeseries. I wish to use the date / times on the x axis and plot the corresponding values of another column on the y axis. I can get this to work but I also want to colour the data points according to the values of a third column. All the examples I've found online seem to through up one sort of error or another.

A reproducible example is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

mydatetimes=pd.to_datetime(['2015-05-01 18:00:12', '2015-05-01 18:01:12', 
                            '2015-05-01 18:02:12', '2015-05-01 18:03:12',
                            '2015-05-01 18:04:12', '2015-05-01 18:05:11',
                            '2015-05-01 18:06:11', '2015-05-01 18:07:11',
                            '2015-05-01 18:08:12', '2015-05-01 18:09:12',
                            '2015-05-01 18:10:12', '2015-05-01 18:11:12'])

myvalues = np.array([45.0, 34.0, 35.0, 45.0, 23.0, 67.0, 
                    78.0, 23.0, 87.0, 32.0, 58.0, 71.0])

myothervalues = np.array([803, 743, 682, 622, 562, 502, 
                          383, 323, 263, 202, 142, 82])

mydatadf = pd.DataFrame({'mydates': mydatetimes, 'data1': myvalues, 'data2': myothervalues})

plt.plot(mydatadf.mydates, mydatadf.data1, '.', c=cm.viridis(mydatadf.data2))
plt.show()
```

Does anyone know of a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `plt.scatter` instead of `plt.plot` if you want each point to have its own color. Also plot the values. You'll only need to change your plot line to:

```
# Set the plot limit
marg = pd.Timedelta(1, 'm')
_ = plt.xlim(mydatadf.mydates.min()-marg, mydatadf.mydates.max()+marg)

plt.scatter(mydatadf.mydates.values, mydatadf.data1.values,
            c=mydatadf.data2.values)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Works a charm. Thanks.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for the correction! I should have noticed calling `cm.viridis(value)` was saturating anything with a `value` 255 and above.